# Rule based number format - Indian currency

Tags: java, groovy, icu

http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html

Using the above class,

```
def format = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(new Locale("en", "in"), RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT)
format.format(value)
```

for    ₹ 9,00,000 value, it shows `nine hundred thousand` . But we have to show `nine lakhs.` How to do this?

Comment: There is a Hindi rbnf data but the names are in Hindy, meaning that `new RuleBasedNumberFormat( new Locale( "hi" ), RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT )` displays a string that looks like `nine lakhs` but in Hindi. As far as i can tell the Icu4j has no ready to use rbnf data that contains lakh cardinal spelled in english.

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedNumberFormat;

public class StringDisplayUtils {


        public static String toWords(Double num) {
            return ((NumberFormat) (new RuleBasedNumberFormat(String.join("\n",
                        "Zero;One;Two;Three;Four;Five;Six;Seven;Eight;Nine;Ten;",
                        "Eleven;Twelve;Thirteen;Fourteen;Fifteen;Sixteen;Seventeen;Eighteen;Nineteen;",
                        "20: Twenty[ >>];",
                        "30: Thirty[ >>];",
                        "40: Forty[ >>];",
                        "50: Fifty[ >>];",
                        "60: Sixty[ >>];",
                        "70: Seventy[ >>];",
                        "80: Eighty[ >>];",
                        "90: Ninety[ >>];",
                        "1,00: << Hundred[ >>];",
                        "1,000: << Thousand[ >>];",
                        "1,000,00: << Lakh[ >>];",
                        "1,000,00,00: << Crore[ >>];",
                        "1,000,00,00,000,00,00,00: OUT OF RANGE!;"
                    )))).format(num);
        }
}
```

this might help!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you will get that. As per the [javadoc](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html), this is the nomenclature they have... beyond thousand

```
 1,000,000: << million[ >>];
 1,000,000,000: << billion[ >>];
 1,000,000,000,000: << trillion[ >>];
 1,000,000,000,000,000: OUT OF RANGE!;
```

IMHO, you need to write custom logic.
For e.g replace all "hundrend thousand" with lakh

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where can i change it?

Comment: the format.format(value) will give you the string output. You can do the replace operation on the string.

Comment: @Hirak, that nomenclature is just an example.Different rbnf data sets can have different nomenclature.